# How to show notification bubbles?

Tags: notification, notification-area

I'm using herbstluftwm as my window manager, and I am not getting any notification bubbles.

How can I enable them? Is there a type of application that manages this? How does it work? What is the type of information I need to be looking for?

Can you share your way of displaying notifications? Any info will be appreciated.

Comment: I use `xfce4-notifyd` for my OpenBox setup, it should work out of the box.

Comment: And you may need to install *libnotify-bin*.

Comment: Thanks guys - I also needed to start the notifyd service `systemctl --user start xfce4-notifyd` Notifications are now showing!